# Batch file loses logs in loops

Tags: batch-file, robotframework

I have various test cases in a folder that require me to make continuous loops. To try this I tried making a batch script that would loop the test cases. However the earlier completed iterations would be lost and only the most recent iteration would be kept. How can I keep the XML logs of all the iterations?

My batch file looks like this:

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,300) DO (
     call pybot --name *.robot
)
```

Comment: Use `>>` in place of `>` (append in place of create anew)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to have your script tell robot to give a unique name to the output file generated by each iteration of the loop. You will then need an extra step to combine all of those outputs into one.

First, generating unique output files:

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,300) DO (
     call pybot --output output-%%A.xml *.robot
)
```

Note: by default `pybot` will generate log.html and report.html. If you want to generate a single unified log and report, you might want to suppress them within the loop. If so, add `--log none --report none` before the filenames to prevent these files from being created in the loop.

Next, you can use rebot to join all of those individual reports into a single report:

```
call rebot *.xml
```

I don't know if `rebot` is a known command on your system -- it's part of robot but I don't know how you installed things on your system. Generally speaking, if `pybot` is a valid command, `rebot` should be too. For more information on rebot see [Post-processing outputs](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#post-processing-outputs) in the robot framework user guide.

---

Note: you seem to have a bug in your batch script. When you do `call pybot --name *.robot`, the very first file will not get run as a test since it will be given to the `--name` option rather than be treated as a test file that should be run.

Answer (score 2):

Specify explicitly the log file names, with these parameters:

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,300) DO (
     call pybot --output otput_%%A.html --log log_%%A.html --report report_%%A.html *.robot
)
```

Have in mind any selenium screenshots will still be overwritten though (if you are using selenium in your tests).

Comment: As written this will fail. The names of the files need come after the options (eg: --output, etc)

Comment: It's still not correct. `--log_%%A.html` isn't a valid option.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,300) DO (
     call pybot --name *.robot
)>>afilename.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve my issue as I want to maintain the XML logs, not the cmd logs.

Comment: @downvoter : OP originally omitted "XML" from the question.

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ : Really? Using the redirector as shown will record the `logs` (as originally requested by OP) to the file nominated, solving the original unexpanded problem posted.

Comment: @Magoo An answer without explanations is useless for the OP and the other visitor who needs to understand the solution.